# Getting data out of an AoT Dictionary in Unity using Visual Scripting

Tags: unity

I have a NormalizedWidth AoT Dictionary with a Key of type String (basically, the alphabet)... and a Value of type Float.  You can see it on the left side of this screenshot:

[image]

Here's what I'm doing: I have a string with five characters in a word.  I'm splitting that string into a char array, and then looping through that array with a For Each Loop.

[image]

What I'd like to do is look up with the width of each of those characters, which is stored in a NormalizedWidth AoT Dictionary.  Or at least I am trying to!  I am currently using a Get Dictionary Item node to try and get values out of the.  But as each character is sent into the node, the output is given as Null.  (See picture above).

I must be making a mistake.  The data appears to be there, but I am failing to access it.  Should I be using a different node to get data out of the Dictionary... or is there another mistake I'm making?  Thank you!

Comment: regardless that it does not work, why do you want to save the Data from a dictionary to another Array? If you need the value for computation of the width of a word later, you can ask directly your dictionary letter by letter

Comment: Either way, I will have to ask my dictionary letter by letter...  just having a bit of trouble doing that here!

Comment: You don't need a dictionary for this, since letters form a dense, contiguous sequence of indices (say, using their ASCII codes). Unless you're trying to work with far-flung Unicode characters beyond the basic ASCII set you've shown here.

Comment: I have 2 data sets: first a dictionary of every glyph in my font (the key) and its width (the valie)... and then an array of letters in a particular word.  Is a dictionary a good way to store the first data set? And how do I get data out of a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `ToCharArray` will generate a `char[]`, in which each element is of type `char` instead of `string`, which is confusing because some nodes on the bolt interface are generic, which prevents the display of the types. You can convert the key to string type through the `ToString` method:

[image]

You can see the difference in their colors on the runtime bolt interface(which is very obscure):

[image]

Edit:

What if I don't have an `Object.ToString` node? Visual Scripting allows you to define your own assemblies. You can decide which nodes are needed. This can save *memory/search time/time of recompiling nodes.etc*. For example, maybe your 2D project doesn't need the unity VR/AR modules, you can cancel them manually.

Maybe you deleted some assemblies manually causing the System assembly to be missing. And `Object` is in it.

Go to `Edit` > `Project Settings` > `Visual Scripting` > `Node Library`:

[image]

You can simply reset the configuration because the default configuration includes System (referenced by other assemblies). You can also manually click `+` to add System.

And dont forget to click `Regenerate Nodes` button.

If it doesn't work still, try to reset the configuration of `Type Options`, and regenerate it again.

Finally, search for `object.tostring` in the script interface:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was hoping for!  I am using Unity Visual Scripting though, and the Object to String node doesn't work to convert a Char to a String.  Any ideas on what node will convert a Char to a String in UVS?

Comment: This seems impossible, `char` inherits from `ValueType`, ultimately inherits from `Object`. This node works fine for me.

Comment: I don't have an Object to String node... but do have a GameObject to String and Unity Object to String. When I try the latter, I get this: InvalidConversionException: Cannot convert from 'System.Char' to 'UnityEngine.Object'.  When I try the former, I get this: InvalidConversionException: Cannot convert from 'System.Char' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.

Comment: @kanamekun Added a possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added System to the Visual Scripting > Node Library and Regenerated Nodes... but I am still not seeing the Object to String node appear when I do a search for "Object.ToString".   I do see the Game Object: To String and the Unity Object: To String and the Scriptable Object: To String!

Comment: Did you click `Regenerate Nodes` after adding System?

Comment: I did Regenerate...

Comment: how about reset the configuration of `Type Options`? (And regenerate again)

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick!! It's working!!!!!